# Java declaring a String array in method invocation

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm trying to declare a String array within a method invocation, like so:

```
if (emailYaml.keySet().containsAll(new String[]{"mailto","subject","text"}))
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is the best approach in any case (i'm pretty new to programming), but in any case Eclipse tells me:

```
The method containsAll(Collection<?>) in the type Set<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String[])
```

Could anyone help with a solution?

Many thanks

Comment: `Arrays.asList("mailto","subject","text")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array isn't a subtype of `Collection`. Convert it to a `List` for example, before passing it to `containsAll`:

```
.containsAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"mailto", "subject", "text"}))
```

Or even simplier, since `asList` takes a vararg as parameter:

```
.containsAll(Arrays.asList("mailto", "subject", "text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Contains all accepts a collection.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
containsAll(Collection<?> c)
```

Try this insead:

```
if (emailYaml.keySet().containsAll(Arrays.asList("mailto","subject","text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`containsAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) expects a `Collection` and you are passing an array, thus your compiler complains.

```
if (emailYaml.keySet().containsAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]
  {"mailto","subject","text"})))
```

Comment: easier: `if (emailYaml.keySet().containsAll(Arrays.asList("mailto","subject","text")))`